# Input from jtextfield doesnt get read while in a for loop

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jtextfield, event-dispatch-thread

My problem is that I have a for loop and while this loop is running I still want inputs from JTextField to get read and not interrupt the loop or timing when the line gets printed.

```
public class test {

    public void Play() {

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyChecker());
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.add(textField);
        jframe.setSize(200, 30);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class KeyChecker extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i = 0)
        {
            char Input = event.getKeyChar();
            if(Input == 'a')
            {
                System.out.println("working");
            } else {
                System.out.println("not working");
            }
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Why do you want to loop there? And why the inifite loop? 2) Don't do long running tasks (and especially don't sleep) on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) since this freezes the GUI.

Comment: at least for now I want an infinite loop and I want that at the same rate something gets printed but this changes when a specific button gets pressed. what should I use to wait before the loop repeats instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the `keyPressed` method gets called by the Event Dispatch Thread (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) every time you press a key in the textfield.

In this context the `KeyEvent event` parameter represents a sing key press event, so it makes no sense to create a loop inside an event method, as maloomeister correctly pointed out.

Instead you should perform your logic using the state of your classes, either `KeyChecker` or `test`.
I don't really understand why you should regularly check for a key being pressed (and the purpose of a textfield BTW), anyway the following is a possible solution using a separate thread.
Of course you can also do the loop in the main thread (which is **not** the EDT), but in a non-trivial application you should never do that.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyChecker keyChecker = new KeyChecker();
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(40);
        textField.addKeyListener(keyChecker);
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.add(textField);
        jframe.pack();
        jframe.setVisible(true);

        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            while(true) {
                char currentKey = keyChecker.getCurrentPressedKey();
                switch (currentKey) {
                    case 'a':
                        System.out.println("working");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("not working");
                }
                    
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        
        t.start();
    }
}

class KeyChecker extends KeyAdapter {
    private char currentPressedKey = 0;

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        currentPressedKey = event.getKeyChar();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        currentPressedKey=0;
    }
    
    public char getCurrentPressedKey() {
        return currentPressedKey;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation as this is my first question